# A javax.swing.text.BadLocationException exception keeps opening

Tags: java, netbeans, exception

This exception keeps popping up every couple seconds or so as I'm typing:

[image]

Show Details:

[image]

The only thing I can think that I've changed is two things:

1. Comments for JavaDocs.
2. Code to close all PreparedStatements and ResultSets after I've finished with them.

It only happens in one class, but literally pops up every couple of seconds. It has just literally started doing this. Any idea why?

OS X - Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 - Java

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (Sorry for being patronising I just want to know...)

Comment: I assume you mean Netbeans? That's fine, I haven't as I wanted to be able to do a batch of undos but I'm sure Netbeans has a history if anything. I'll try now!

Comment: Seems to be fine so far. As I enter and exit the class which was throwing the error every couple of seconds, nothing happens now. Very weird! Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's ok :) Glad I could help! I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it if others have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning NetBeans on and off again?